# Analytical Reasoning Question II

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have yet another analytical question that got me

*A five-digit number is formed using digits 1, 3, 5, 7 and 9 without repeating any one of them. What is the sum of all such possible numbers?*

Please kindly explain your final answer so those of us who are still trying to learn can grasp the logic easily. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The number of possible combinations is $5! = 120$. Each digit will be in each position an equal number of times, namely
$5!/5 = 24$ times.

So the sum of the digits in the one's place is

$24(1+3+5+7+9) = 24*25 = 600$

This will be the sum of the digits in each place (one's, ten's, etc.). So the total sum is:

$600*11,111 = 6,666,600$,
regards,
iyengar

Comment: but let me ask,is my answer right ??,as i am not a person with formal training,

Comment: Why do you need this line? $24(1+3+5+7+9) = 24*25 = 600$. Why sum the numbers? I don't know the answer yet(trying not to look in the back of the book for the answers until I am sure I have this right).:)

Comment: My question is, why add the individual allowable digits, rather than just adding the total occurrence for each? I was thinking more something like this $24(5) = 24*5 = 120$

Comment: For each decimal place, 24 of these are of the same digit.

Thus for a decimal place the total value is 24 (1 + 3 + 5 + 7 + 9)
= 600
To get the total value of all these numbers multiply the first result by 11111.

Answer (score 3):

As a slight alternative to iyengar's answer:

There are $120$ such numbers and their average is $55555$ (note that for any of the form, there is also $111110$ minus that number) so the answer is $120\times 55555=6666600$.

Comment: where did you get 55555 from? The question specifies that there are no repeats allowed.

Comment: If you have for example $17935$ then you also have $111110-17935=93175$, so the average term is half $111110$, namely $55555$.

Comment: I am sorry, I still don't get the 111110 and the 55555. Why those?

Answer (score 3):

This is partly a slight variant of Henry’s answer and partly a further explanation in answer to one of your questions.

If $d$ is one of the allowable digits $1,3,5,7,9$, let $d' = 10 - d$; note that $d'$ is also allowable. Now let $abcde$ be any allowable number; then $a'b'c'd'e'$ is also allowable, and it must be a different number from $abcde$. (It would be the same number only if all of the digits were $5$, but that’s not allowed.) In this way you can pair up all of the allowable numbers. Since there are $5! = 120$ permutations of the $5$ allowable digits, there are $120$ allowable numbers, and hence there are $60$ of these pairs.

It shouldn’t be too hard to see that $abcde + a'b'c'd'e' = 111110$ no matter which allowable number $abcde$ you start with. That is, the numbers in each pair sum to $111110$. Since there are $60$ pairs, the grand total is $60 \cdot 111110 = 6,666,600$.

Henry did essentially the same thing, except that instead of looking at the sum of $abcde$ and $a'b'c'd'e'$, he looked at their average, $111110/2 = 55555$. Since all pairs have the same average, the entire collection of allowable numbers must also have that average. And if the $120$ allowable numbers have an average of $55555$, their total must be $120 \cdot 55555 = 6,666,600$.

Comment: I need help seeing this [If $d$ is one of the allowable digits $1,3,5,7,9$, let $d' = 10 - d$; note that $d'$ is also allowable. ] please. Why is $10-d$ allowable?

Comment: Also, how is $abcde + a'b'c'd'e' = 111110$. I don't get that please. Is this binary?

Comment: @user10695: **1st question:** Just do the arithmetic: if $d=1$, $10-d=9$; if $d=3$, $10-d=7$; and so on. Subtracting $1,3,5,7$, or $9$ from $10$ leaves $9,7,5,3$, or $1$, respectively. **2nd question:** Not binary, just ordinary addition. $e+e'=10$, so you write down $0$ and carry $1$. Then $d+d'=10$, and the carry makes $11$, so you write down $1$ and carry $1$. The same thing happens in the remaining three columns, so you end up with a total of $111110$.

Comment: Thanks! What I thought $abcde + a'b'c'd'e' = 111110$ meant was $(a*b*c*d*e) + (a'*b'*c'*d'*e')$ . Now I see what you mean. Thanks for that.

Answer (score 0):

why all this ?

it is so simple
There are 5 digits and as we all know it will 5! numbers (1*2*3*4*5)=120
on a digit place every number will repeat 24 times that is 120/5
on ones place the sum will be 24(1+3+5+7+9)=25*24=600
If u need further explanation why 24(1+3+5+7+9+)
                        see this: at every digit place
                      1 will repeat 24 times 24*1=24
                      3 will repeat 24 times 24*3=72
                      5 will repeat 24 times 24*5=120
                      7 will repeat 24 times 24*7=168
                      9 will repeat 24 times 24*9=216 
total give 600

every digit place will sum to 600
             unit place                    600
             tenth place                  600
             hundreds place              600
             Thousands place            600
             ten thousands place       600
                               --------------------------------
                                       6666600

Comment: Use MathJax please.